# error CS0738 Interface implementation

Tags: c#-4.0, mef

I have the following interface:

public delegate void NotifyOnModulesAvailabilityHandler(Lazy[] modules);

```
public interface IModulesLoader
{
    event NotifyOnModulesAvailabilityHandler NotifyOnModulesAvailability;

    Lazy<UserControl, IModuleMetadata>[] Modules { get; set; }

    void OnImportsSatisfied();
}
```

I'm tring to implement this interface like this:

```
public class ModulesLoader : IModulesLoader, IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    #region Events

    public event NotifyOnModulesAvailabilityHandler NotifyOnModulesAvailability;

    #endregion

    #region Public Contructor

    public ModulesLoader()
    {
        DeploymentCatalogService.Instance.Initialize();

        CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);

        this.LoadModules();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    [ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)]
    public Lazy<UserControl, IModuleMetadata>[] Modules
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification Members

    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        var handler = this.NotifyOnModulesAvailability;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this.Modules);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private void LoadModules()
    {
        var wc = new WebClient();
        wc.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            var streamInfo = e.Result;

            var xElement = XElement.Load(streamInfo);

            var modulesList = from m in xElement.Elements("ModuleInfo")
                              select m;
            if (modulesList.Any())
            {
                foreach (var module in modulesList)
                {
                    var moduleName = module.Attribute("XapFilename").Value;

                    DeploymentCatalogService.Instance.AddXap(moduleName);
                }
            }
        };
        wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("ModulesCatalog.xml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

I get the following error:

> Error 1   'TunisiaMeeting.Extensibility.Shell.Helpers.Deployment.ModulesLoader' does not implement interface member 'TunisiaMeeting.MefBase.Interfaces.IModulesLoader.Modules'. 'TunisiaMeeting.Extensibility.Shell.Helpers.Deployment.ModulesLoader.Modules' cannot implement 'TunisiaMeeting.MefBase.Interfaces.IModulesLoader.Modules' because it does not have the matching return type of ``` 'System.Lazy``2<System.Windows.Controls.UserControl,TunisiaMeeting.MefBase.Interfaces.IModuleMetadata>[]' ```.   C:\Imed\TunisiaMeeting\TunisiaMeeting.Extensibility.Shell\Helpers\Deployment\ModulesLoader.cs   18  18  TunisiaMeeting.Extensibility.Shell

I'm pretty sure I have the same return Type `Lazy<UserControl, IModuleMetadata>[]` in both my class and my interface for my property.

Any Help please ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown where `UserControl` and `IModuleMetadata` come from... my guess is that your interface is referring to one pair of types whereas your implementation is referring to a different pair:

- Make sure they're referring to the same types in the same namespaces
- Make sure you only have one copy of each type (e.g. that you haven't got one copy in a class library, and redeclared it somewhere else)

Comment: This is my IModuleMetadata:

namespace TunisiaMeeting.MefBase.Interfaces
{
    public interface IModuleMetadata
    {
        string XapFilename { get; }
        string NavigateUri { get; set; }
        string Title { get; }
        int Position { get; }
    }
}

and UserControl is System.Windows.Controls.UserControl

They Both refer to the same namespace, I one copy of each type

Comment: @Imed: So you've only got that declaration of `IModuleMetaData` in one assembly?

Comment: Yes I got it in my MefBase project

namespace TunisiaMeeting.MefBase.Interfaces
{
    public interface IModuleMetadata
    {
        string XapFilename { get; }
        string NavigateUri { get; set; }
        string Title { get; }
        int Position { get; }
    }
}

Comment: And I refer to it by project reference

Comment: MefBase Project is in the same solution